# Update relative path to "partially" absolute path in .html files

Tags: bash, sh, relative-path, absolute-path

There is a set of `.html` files located in different folders.
Lets say the structure is:

```
--folder
|--files.html
|--filename.html
--folder2
|--files.html
```

In `files.html` there is a reference like `href="filename.html"`. In fact, when you see such reference, it means that the `filename.html` is located in the same folder as the `files.html` that references it. Instead of this `href`, the `href` should be `href="folder/filename.html"`.

There can be a large number of folders and many files with such reference, and I cannot hardcode the names.

Is there a way to scan the files and do infile replacements using bash?

Comment: have a look af the `find(1)` command for searching files recursively and probably `sed(1)` for editing the files.

Comment: You shouldn't need to make that change.  If the browser is displaying "folder/files.html", then the relative URL "filename.html" will refer to "folder/filename.html".  What problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way to accomplish this in Bash. Better look for software developed particularly for this task.

Comment: Yeah, I agree that the request is against the nature. But the website where those htmls are hosted does not handle this type of links. It **expects** to see the pattern like `href='folder/file.html'` even if the files **are located** in the same folder

Answer (score 0):

First things first: With plain HTML that won't be possible. You can write a shell script to update the files.html, but you have to run this after each modification of the file tree. (Hinting you to `sed` and `ls -m` (EDIT: `ls` might be even better than `ls -m`, because you probably don't need the comma in between.))

There are options to automate creating the file-listing though, but they require some additions. Before elaborating on those, could you please update your question about the following things?

Could you please add details about the webserver?
Depending on that, there might be additional options.
See http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_autoindex_module.html, https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_autoindex.html, and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/directorybrowse.

In case you're using those HTML files without a webserver, what about javascript? Could that be an option?

In general: It is probably easier to help you solve the original task than something so "abstract" and in this case "rare". Would be great to know what you're actually trying to solve, so we can get to the base of that.